# writing an interpreter in java using multiple arraylists or arrays with stringtokenizer

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, stringtokenizer

I'm currently working on an assignment to create a basic interpreter with 8 keywords (case insensitive) and the 4 arithmetic operators. A program in this language would look something like this (similar to BASIC's syntax really):

```
# (signals start of a comment line)
LET
INTEGER
STRING
PRINT
END
```

So anyway I'm currently trying to tokenize the lines of text to be parsed. I already parsed all the lines of text into an ArrayList and tokenized the Strings. My current problem now is that StringTokenizer tokenizes all the strings in advance (I'm using whitespace as a delimiter), when what I need is for it to find my keyword, which is always the first word at the beginning of the line of code, and certain issues make that undesirable; I don't think that using String.split() would be much help either.

The way I was planning on doing it was to have the interpreter find my  first token, and go from there to the appropriate class via the HashMap (cf. my previous question regarding the use of switch statements for my interpreter here: [Switch or if statements in writing an interpreter in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772241/switch-or-if-statements-in-writing-an-interpreter-in-java/8773950#8773950); it was suggested by other members that I use a Map) to remove the keyword token and execute. Would setting up a second temporary ArrayList or array specifically to hold variables be a good idea? I don't want or need it to be overly complicated.

Thanks in advance for the suggestions.

```
public static void main (String[]args)
    {
        try
        {
            ArrayList<String> demo= new ArrayList <String>();
            FileReader fr= new FileReader("hi.tpl");
            BufferedReader reader= new BufferedReader(fr);
            String line;
            while ((line=reader.readLine()) !=null)//read file line by line
                {
                    //Add to ArrayList
                    demo.add(line);
                }

            reader.close();

            boolean checkEnd= demo.contains("END");//check if arraylist contains END statement
                    if(line=null && checkEnd== false)
                        {
                            System.out.println(" Unexpected end of file: no END statement");
                            System.exit(0);
                        }

            ListIterator<String>arrayListIt=demo.listIterator();
            while (arrayListIt.hasNext())
            for (String file: demo)// begin interpreting the program file here
                {               
                    StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(file);
                    while(st.hasMoreTokens())
                        {

                            int firstWord=file.indexOf();
                            String command = file;
                            if (firstSpace > 0)
                            {
                                command= file.substring(0, firstSpace);
                            }
                            TokenHandler tokens= tokens.get(command.toUpperCase());
                            if(tokens != null)
                            {
                                tokens.execute(file);
                            }

                        }
```

Comment: It's not clear what your question is.

Comment: @JBNizet I was asking whether or not I should consider parsing the arguments in a method, or parse all of the arguments and put it into a separate ArrayList from the one I have that holds the lines of script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I were doing it I'd use a more OO approach.

What if you created a "Class" for each of those commands that all implemented the same interface?  The interface--let's call it CommandObject would have an execute() method.

You could then use a pre-loaded map that mapped the command like "Let" to an instance of the Let class.

Now your main loop becomes something like this (pseudo):

```
for(line:lineList)
    CommandObject commandObject=map.get(line.split()[0]) // do this more clearly
    commandObject.execute(variableHash, line) // Parse and execute the line
```

These command objects would have to share a set of variables--making a singleton would work but is somewhat of an anti-pattern, I suggest you pass them in as a hashmap (variableHash above) instead.

The nice thing about this approach is that adding a new "Command" is very simple and mostly independent.

Edit (re. comment):

The first thing you would do is create a hashmap and "Install" each of your commands.  For example: (still psudeo-code, I assume you'd prefer to do the assignment yourself)

```
map = new HashMap<String, CommandObject>
```

then add an instance of each class to the map:

```
map.put("LET", new LetCommand());
map.put("INTEGER", new Integercommand());
```

where the right-hand classes implement the "CommandObject" interface.

Notice that since each CommandObject is an instance that is re-used every time that keyword is found you should probably not store ANY state (Don't have any instance variables), this implies that your CommandObject will only require a single method, something like:

```
execute(String commandLine, HashMap variables);
```

This is probably the easiest way (I edited the text above from my original suggestion to reflect this).

If this parser got more complex it would be totally valid to add more functionality to "CommandObject"s, you could keep state variables as long as you had a reset() method (my original suggestion but it seems overly complicated for what you are doing)

Note that the map of keywords to command objects could be replaced by reflection but don't try to do that for a school assignment, the complexity of reflection makes it not worth your time and it's likely you'd be downgraded because the teacher doesn't understand it. I implemented a system like this where every keyword linked to a test (allowing you to chain tests, loop over tests and even define and carry variables that were passed into and manipulated by those tests--in this case reflection was worth it because adding a new test did not require updating the cache)

Comment: This is kinda what I was trying to shoot for: I wanted something where adding a new keyword would be fairly simple. Although, could you explain more about passing the commands in as a hashmap? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much @Bill K, this is awesome. I've gotten started on the HashMap already.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the correct design would be to put off parsing these arguments until later. Certain commands like "STRING" or "PRINT" might be whitespace-agnostic, where STRING S = "HELLO WORLD" really wouldn't be functionally different from STRING S = "HELLOWORLD". You don't want to "over-engineer" stuff like this up front - it's better just to do the simplest thing that works now, write one or two of your command classes, and then figure out what those command classes have in common.

If you later discover that all (or most) of your commands want these arguments parsed into a list in a certain way, you can refactor that "list parsing code" into a static utility method (or possibly, a non-static utility method on the parent Command class itself, if you're using inheritance.) This will be much less risky if you are smart about creating a suite of automated tests as you go along, but that kind of task might fall outside the scope of your assignment.

Answer (score 0):

One nice way is using an `enum`. And I would not refrain from using `split` with a limit to 2 items.

```
enum Command {
    LET {
        @Override
        public void execute(Context context, String args) {
        }
    },
    INTEGER { ... },
    STRING { ... },
    PRINT { ... },
    END { ... };

    public abstract void execute(Context context, String args);
}

private void executeLine(String line) {
    String[] commandAndArgs = line.split("\\s+", 2);
    String command = "";
    String args = "";
    if (commandAndArgs.length > 0)
        command = commandArgs[0].toUpperCase();
    if (commandAndArgs.length > 1)
        args = commandArgs[1];
    Command cmd = Command.valueOf(command);
    Context context = ...;
    cmd.execute(context, args);
}
```